# URL with /something/something

Tags: java, html, spring

All my pages are in one folder.

For Example for the test cases i have :

`create-test-case.jsp`, `edit-test-case.jsp`, `remove-test-case.jsp`

So when I click this pages on the menu I get: `localhost:8080/create-test-case`

What I actually wanted is

`localhost:8080/testCase/create`

How do I do this?

I'm using SPRING MVC

Comment: what's the method that gets hits that returns that url?

Comment: You can create TestCaseController which will have methods to navigate your requests.